# customize rails4 delete popup box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Please guide me how to customize my delete popup box of rails I want to give my own design. I had given this in my view:

```
<td class="text-center">
   <%= link_to delete, user_path(user.id), method: :delete, :remote => true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', no_turbolink: true } %>
</td>
```

and my popup html code is

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
          <p  class="margin_B0"><a href="#"class="place-right" ><img src="images/close_icon.png" width="13" height="13"></a></p>
          <div class="row margin_T5 margin_B0 bg-white">
            <div class="row">
              <p>Text goes here</p>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
              <input type="button" value="CANCEL" class="button meduim text_upper buttons_orange">
              <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="button meduim text_upper buttons_orange">
            </div>
          </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

please help me out where I will write my own view of popup box.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to delete, user_path(user.id), method: :delete, :remote => true, data: { popup: true, no_turbolink: true } %>

$('a[data-popup]').on('click', function(e) { 
    var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200, height=100");   // Opens a new window; 
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");   // Text in the new window

    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

try something like this

Comment: where I will give my customize view code am not getting that actually.

Comment: Use "window.open" to create popup and "document.write" to add content in popup

Comment: No its always giving **Are you sure?** only nothing is been changed its not working :(

Comment: my question is also same as above but only change is I have to give close icon i.e `close_icon.png` in my popup box. I hope i have to pass some thing in my  `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?', no_turbolink: true } ` . But am not getting how to do this.